# What's wrong with my code (Beginner) (Java)

Tags: java

I was doing some Java just to practice, and decided to do a Dungeons & Dragons type code. (This is just rolling for character stats)

I typed in everything, and it keeps saying (character)'s greatest stat was vitality. Help?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DAndD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        System.out.println("Choose a name for your Dungeons & Dragons       character.");
        String character = input.next();
        System.out.print("Ah, " + character + " has a nice ring to  it.\nLet's roll for stats shall we?");
        int str = generator.nextInt(21);
        int dex = generator.nextInt(21);
        int intel = generator.nextInt(21);
        int wis = generator.nextInt(21);
        int vit = generator.nextInt(21);

        if (str > 0);
        String trait = "strength";
        int large = str;
        if (dex > large);
        trait = "dexterity";
        large = dex;
        if (intel > large);
        trait = "intelligence";
        large = intel;
        if (wis > large);
        trait = "wisdom";
        large = wis;
        if (vit > large);
        trait = "vitality";
        large = vit;


        if(large == str){
        System.out.println("\n" + character + "'s best stat is its strength!");
        }
        else if (large == dex){
        System.out.println("\n" + character + "'s best stat is its dexterity!");
        }
        else if (large == intel){
        System.out.println("\n" + character + "'s best stat is its intelligence!");
        }
        else if (large == wis){
        System.out.println("\n" + character + "'s best stat is its wisdom!");
        }
        else if (large == vit){
        System.out.println("\n" + character + "'s best stat is its vitality");
        }
        System.out.println("\nStrength: " + str + "\nDexterity:" + dex + "\nIntelligence: " + intel + "\nWisdom: " + wis + "\nVitality: " + vit);

        }
}
```

So, this is what the end result looks like as of now:

**OUTPUT**

```
Choose a name for your Dungeons & Dragons character.

*Toetar*

Ah, Toetar has a nice ring to it.

Let's roll for stats shall we?

Toetar's best stat is its vitality

Strength: 5

Dexterity: 19

Intelligence: 1

Wisdom: 6

Vitality: 4
```

Answer (score 5):

You have semicolons (`;`) after your if statements (`if (vit > large);`), which are negating their functionality.  This is why it's important to use `{...}`

I "assume" you mean something more like...

```
String trait = "";
int large = -1;
if (str > 0) {
    trait = "strength";
    large = str;
} else if (dex > large) {
    trait = "dexterity";
    large = dex;
} else if (intel > large) {
    trait = "intelligence";
    large = intel;
} else if (wis > large) {
    trait = "wisdom";
    large = wis;
} else if (vit > large) {
    trait = "vitality";
    large = vit;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering to know if I say the ; terminate the boolean evaluation from this following statement if(str>0) and the rest will not be seen by the compiler? is it better to explain it like that?

Comment: My bad... I saw someone doing this before while they were asking questions and assumed semicolons were possible after if-statements. I know realize the problem the problem with my code was copied from their own problem.... -_-

Comment: Semicolons are possible after `if` statements, it just means that everything after the semicolon is executed, which you don't want to happen, you want to only execute the following lines `if` the condition is matched...

Comment: @KickButtowski I don't know if the compiler would optimise the code to remove the condition in these circumstances...

Comment: @MadProgrammer at compile time compiler will through an error ya?

Comment: @CobyWalters You can also use `if (str > 0) trait = "strength";`, but  `"strength"` will only be applied if `str> 0` and then all the other lines of code will be executed after it.  This is generally why it's better to use `{...}`, it'll save you a lot of issues

Comment: @KickButtowski Nope, the compiler will assume you know what you're doing :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is gonna run no matter what except no deseried output

Comment: @KickButtowski Pretty much or at least in this case, the outcome will the same. Normally I'd say it was a NOOP (or no operation), but I thought that might be a little confusing for the OP

Answer (score 1):

The statements after your `if` are never evaluated when the the condition expression inside `if` is `true` because you have kept a `semi-colon` after your `if` which won't consider your next statement to be part of conditional `if` block:

For example :

```
if (str > 0);  // you have kept ; semi-colon so it does nothing
String trait = "strength";  // this is independent of above statement
```

Also, as suggested by @MadProgrammer in above answer, if you use this :

```
if (str > 0) {
    String trait = "strength";
    int large = str;
}
```

Your variable `trait`,`large` will be accessible only inside your `if` block.

So better first declare them before you start your `ifs` :

```
String trait = "";
int large = 0;

if (str > 0) {
    trait = "strength";
    large = str;
} else if (dex > large) {
    trait = "dexterity";
    large = dex;
}//and so on
```